# ReactJS, Webpack, ExpressJS - How to access styles folder in root

Tags: express, reactjs, webpack

I have the following folder structure ...

```
--- app
    --- components
    index.js
--- server
    index.js
--- data
    data.json
--- styles
    styles.css
--- images
    logo.png
```

In my Express server/index.js I have:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }))
app.use(express.static(rootPath));
// styles folder is at root
app.use('/styles', express.static(rootPath));
```

In webpack.dev.config.js I have

```
  {
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: "style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader",
    include: rootPath
  }
```

While I can successfully access the json file from within the app folder's files,
**I cannot access styles.css in the root folder styles from within the app folder**.
This is what I have so far but I receive the error ...

**Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' /styles/styles.css**

And this is what I have in my react Index.js file ....

```
require('/styles/styles.css');
```

How can I access my styles folder at the root level when coding react files in the app folder?

Comment: With webpack, you don't need to serve your styles as static. By the way, it's a good practice to make individual css (actually, you should use sass) for every component, and place them in the same directory. [Here is an example.](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mounted the root folder at `/styles`, I would imagine the URL would need to be `/styles/styles/styles.css`. More than likely you're looking for something more like this:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }))
app.use(express.static(rootPath));
// mount the *contents* of the styles folder to `/styles`
app.use('/styles', express.static(path.join(rootPath, "styles")));
```

However, if you access the file directly, it will not be processed by webpack.

Comment: Thanks, that did it for me, but I did not need to use styles/styles. Only 1 /styles sufficed.